# Error generated by MicroSoft JET database, engine could not delete from specified tables

Tags: runtime-error

An error was generated by MicroSoft JET database engine, could not delete from specified tables.

How can i fix this in order to run my program?

I installed the 2017 version of MicroSoft Visual Studio C++, but the issue persisted. I am expecting it to run smoothly and be able to project and to be used by a projector.

Comment: "Microsoft JET" refers to either the "JET Red" MS Access `.mdb`/`.accdb` engine, or the "JET Blue" engine, aka ESE/ESENT for `.edb` files. Please clarify how you're using Jet and exactly what software is involved.